Globally JSON-serializing UUIDs and other types with psycopg2 and django
I'm developing an application with Django 4.2.10. I am running a postgres database and use psycopg2. In my application, I am working with nested dictionaries (coming out of Django ninja/pydantic schemas) and I would like to write these to JSONField django fields. However, they contain UUID's which results in the following error:
TypeError: Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable

To resolve this problem, I really prefer a "global" hook/adapter that convinces psycopg2 to properly serialize UUID's and other types so that I don't have to worry about it in all the places where I write this data into the database. It should work for direct/raw queries but also via the Django ORM.
I found this JSON Adaptation section in the psycopg2 docs.

Note You can use register_adapter() to adapt any Python dictionary to JSON, either registering Json or any subclass or factory creating a compatible adapter:
psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(dict, psycopg2.extras.Json)
This setting is global though, so it is not compatible with similar adapters such as the one registered by register_hstore(). Any other object supported by JSON can be registered the same way, but this will clobber the default adaptation rule, so be careful to unwanted side effects.

So my thought was that if I would subclass psycopg2.extras.Json, I could override the serialization behaviour. I did the following experiment:
# my django model

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    allow = models.JSONField(default=list, null=False, blank=True)


# my test code

from uuid import uuid4
import orjson
from app.models import SomeModel
from psycopg2.extras import Json
from psycopg2.extensions import adapt, register_adapter, AsIs
from django.db import connection

def json_default(o):
    # This allows me to easily add support for other types!
    match o:
        case set():
            return list(o)
        case UUID():
            return str(o)
    return str

class MyJson(Json):
    def dumps(self, obj):
        # print for debugging
        print(obj)
        return orjson.dumps(obj, default=json_default)

# register my custom adapter
register_adapter(dict, MyJson)
    
# test data
mydict = {"a": "b", "c": uuid4()}

# Raw query adapts UUID correctly!
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO app_somemodel (name, allow) VALUES (%s, %s)",
            ("a", mydict))

# This fails: TypeError: Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable
SomeModel.objects.create(name="a", allow=mydict)

The stacktrace suggests that Django simply refuses to call my MyJson object and uses the default one at psycopg2/_json.py:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 822, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 909, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1071, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1112, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1847, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1823, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_json.py", line 78, in getquoted
    s = self.dumps(self.adapted)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nathan/.virtualenvs/djangotest/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_json.py", line 72, in dumps
    return self._dumps(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

I'm completely at a loss here. How is it possible that Django completely ignores my adapter and still executes the default one? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
